# how to load one specific xps document into DocumentViewer for reading without loading it when application start

Tags: c#, wpf, xps

I only made a button to add a document.
Is it possible to somehow load a document from a folder with a Visual Studio project or something else?

```
private void Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "XPS file (*.xps)|*.xps";

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(ofd.FileName, FileAccess.Read);
                documentViewer.Document = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is unclear what is your intension but you can include a existing file in the application resources and load it when the application starts at run time.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Book1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 var xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(@"C:documentPath", FileAccess.Read);
 documentViewer.Document = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
}
```